# how to convert html:options collection into html:optionsCollection

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts

how to convert the statement of

```
    <html:options collection='catList' property='catId' labelProperty='catName'>
```

by using `<html:optionsCollection>.`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on the `<html:options>` tag, the `collections` attribute is (http://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/options.html):

> Name of the JSP bean (in some scope) which is itself a Collection of other beans, each of which has properties named by the "property" and "labelProperty" attributes that are used to retrieve the value and label for each option, respectively.

So your `catList` is a collection of beans (that can be in any scope) that have the property `catId` which will be the value for the select and `catName` which will be the displayed label in the select.

To translate this to `<html:optionsCollection>` tag, We should look at the documentation (http://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/optionsCollection.html) :

> This tag differs from the <html:options> tag in that it makes more consistent use of the name and property attributes, and allows the collection to be more easily obtained from the enclosing form bean.

So essentially its using different attributes for the same things to make the wording more consistent. In this case it should look something like:

```
<html:optionsCollection property="catList" value="catId" label="catName">
```

This will get the collection `catList` from the bean that is on the current form and use the `catId` in each of those objects as the value and `catName` as the label.